# Добавление элементов в массив лимит

Tags: python

```
import json
import requests


names = []
def get_names():
    
    n = requests.get('https://old.cs.money/js/database-skins/library-ru-730.js?v=738')
    skins = n.text.replace('skinsBaseList[730] = ', '')
    skins = json.loads(skins)
    for item in skins:
        names.append(skins[item])
        
get_names()
print(len(names))
```

> Result: 17755

Получается 17755, а должно быть 1083043. Но если выводить item, то все итемы будут.
Если брать этот массив до json.loads из файла, а не из запроса, ничего не меняется.
В чем проблема?

Comment: *>должно быть 1083043* - почему?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов если перейти по ссылке и долистать до конца, то последний элемент будет +-1083043-й("1083043":{...})

Comment: Это не значит, что их там 1083043.

Comment: попробуйте написать `print(names[-1])`